# Combination inside switch case

Tags: javascript

I used to have a simple `switch case`, like this:

```js
const expr = 'Papayas';
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
    console.log('Oranges');
    break;
  case 'Mangoes':
    console.log('Mangoes');
    break;
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('Papayas');
    break;
}
```

but now some criteria changed and I need to add one rule for all three cases and leave the old functionality as it was. So in case, I'll have `Papayas`, my resalt would be `All` and `Papayas`. I tried to combine it like this:

```js
const expr = 'Papayas';
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
  case 'Mangoes':
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('All');
  case 'Oranges':
    console.log('Oranges');
    break;
  case 'Mangoes':
    console.log('Mangoes');
    break;
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('Papayas');
    break;
}
```

but that doesn't work correctly. I always get `All` and `Oranges` in the result. Is there a way to do it with one `switch case`?

Comment: You're missing `break;` after `console.log('All');`

Comment: If I'll add `break;` then I won't go to the next `case` and always get only `All`. Without `Papayas`

Comment: What is a valid output? And  would 'Bananas', for example, be a valid input?

Comment: Then what you're asking for isn't really the purpose of `switch`. It's supposed to match *one* case. The fallthrough behaviour can then go to the next but what you're asking for is to match multiple cases.

Comment: @VLAZ I also thought about that but wasn't sure, that's why I created a new question here. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Kleber in my case I receive only `'Oranges'`, `'Mangoes'` or `'Papayas'` as input. So the valid input would be `All`, and `Papayas`, for example

Comment: `switch` doesn't seem like a good option in this use-case.

Comment: err, why should a value of "Papayas" result in both "Papayas" and "All"? "Papayas" isn't "Oranges" and "Mangoes", therefore "All" would be a weird output. Your question seems to indicate simply always logging "All" after the switch would serve your purpose, potentially wrapped in an if statement to ensure the input is one of the three.

Comment: Did you mean, if the input is "All", all three should be logged?

Comment: var `expr` can only hold one value. So your switch doesn't make sense as your first case checks for all values so you have Oranges and the others TWICE. It will pass on the first one and result "All" without reaching the second one. You're using the wrong function for your needs or you're using the wrong value for your needs. You haven't stated the purpose and usage so it's not likely you'll get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```js
const output = ['All'];

switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges':
    output.push('Oranges');
    break;
  case 'Mangoes':
    output.push('Mangoes');
    break;
  case 'Papayas':
    output.push('Papayas');
    break;
}

console.log(...output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I forgot a break?
>
> If you forget a break then the script will run from the case where the criterion is met and will run the cases after that regardless if a criterion was met.
> - [the MDN JS docs on `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

What happens in your case is that it matches the `case 'Papayas': console.log('All')` and then runs the next `case 'Oranges': console.log('Oranges') break;` despite it not being met; afterwards comes the `break` of that case - without this you'd also be outputting `Mangoes` and `Papayas`.

The first, trivial fix is to just duplicate the `console.log('All')` in all switch cases:

```js
switch (expr) {
  case 'Oranges': console.log('All'); console.log('Oranges'); break;
  case 'Mangoes': console.log('All'); console.log('Mangoes'); break;
  case 'Papayas': console.log('All'); console.log('Papayas');
}
```

the last `break` may be omitted. An alternative that requires the use of a second `switch` and duplicating the `case`s is to just execute one `switch` after another:

```js
let val = expr;

switch (val) {
  case 'Oranges':
  case 'Mangoes':
  case 'Papayas':
    console.log('All')
}

switch (val) {
  case 'Oranges': console.log('Oranges'); break;
  case 'Mangoes': console.log('Mangoes'); break;
  case 'Papayas': console.log('Papayas'); break;
}
```

but I'd question **whether a `switch` is the appropriate language construct to use here**. An `if` comes to mind:

```js
let val = expr;
if (val == 'Oranges' || val == 'Mangoes' || val == 'Papayas') {
  console.log('All');
  switch (val) {
    case 'Oranges': console.log('Oranges'); break;
    case 'Mangoes': console.log('Mangoes'); break;
    case 'Papayas': console.log('Papayas'); break;
  }
}
```

**Ideally, you can look up the message in a dictionary / "object" in JS terminology:**

```js
const messages = {
  Oranges: 'Oranges',
  Mangoes: 'Mangoes',
  Papayas: 'Papayas'
}
let message = messages[expr];
if (message) {
  console.log('All');
  console.log(message);
}
```

Alternatively using arrow funcs if your code doesn't consist just of a mapping data -> data but rather data -> action:

```js
const funcs = {
  Oranges: () => console.log('Oranges'),
  Mangoes: () => console.log('Mangoes'),
  Papayas: () => console.log('Papayas')
}
let func = funcs[expr];
if (func) {
  console.log('All');
  func();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take advantage of the way select statements will continue after matching the first item if a `break;` isn't declared.  Example below uses conditional breaks to output the following.

- Input: 'All' = `All - Oranges Mangoes and Papayas`
- Input: 'Oranges' = `Oranges`
- Input: 'MangPap' = `All - Mangoes and Papayas`
- Input: 'Mangoes' = `Mangoes`
- Input: 'Papayas' = `Papayas`
- Input: unrecognized (default) = `Input not recognized.`

```js
const expr = 'MangPap';
var output = '';
switch (expr) {
  case 'All':
    output = 'All - ';
  case 'Oranges':
    if ( output.length > 0 ) { output += 'Oranges'; } else { output += 'Oranges'; }
    if (expr === 'Oranges') { break; }
  case 'MangPap':
    if ( output.length > 0 ) {  } else { output += 'All - '; }
  case 'Mangoes':
    if ( output.length > 0 ) { output += ' Mangoes'; } else { output += 'Mangoes'; }
    if (expr === 'Mangoes') { break; }
  case 'Papayas':
    if ( output.length > 0 ) { output += ' and Papayas'; } else { output += 'Papayas'; }
    if (expr === 'Papayas') { break; }
  default:
    if ( output.length > 0 ) {  } else { output += output = 'Input not recognized.'; }
}
console.log( output );
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: Thanks! But that's not the case. I know about `default`, but in my example, as input, I have one of the `case` and need to get as output `All` and `/input value/`.

Comment: so if "expr" = "All" you want it to match case "All" ?  You've frankly been quite vague.

Comment: @MarkMark have you had a chance to revisit this?